# How to make nested menu with python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I need to write a nested menu for a telegram bot. I am using *python-telegram-bot* and currently have the following code. On the command */caregories* bot receives a list of parent categories from the database using the method *caregory_service.get_parent_categories()* and displays them as menu buttons. I want to add the following functionality to the bot: when you click on each of the category buttons, a submenu opens with a list of subcategories and a back button to return to the list of parent categories. You can get a list of subcategories using the method *caregory_service.get_subcategories()*. When you click on any of the subcategories, it is added to the list of selected ones and this list is returned after pressing the "OK" button in the main menu. How can I implement this with *python-telegram-bot*?

```
from telegram.ext import AIORateLimiter, Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from services import CategoryService

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

async def categories_callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    keyboard = []
    category_service = CategoryService()
    categories = await category_service.get_parent_categories() # get all parent categories from database

    categories_buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(category.name, callback_data=str(category.id))] for category in categories]
    keyboard.extend(categories_buttons)

    keyboard.extend([
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Cancel",
            callback_data="cancel"
        )],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Ok",
            callback_data="confirm"
        )]])

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Some text",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )


def create_bot() -> Application:
    bot = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).rate_limiter(AIORateLimiter()).build()
    bot.add_handler(CommandHandler("categories", categories_callback))
    return bot


async def start_bot() -> Application:
    bot = create_bot()
    await bot.initialize()
    await bot.updater.start_polling()
    await bot.start()
    return bot

bot = start_bot()
```